# Adding "Open With..." Functionality c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a program that can read, write, and export files, these functions all work fine and are almost perfected. What I would like to do now is to be able to choose a file and tell it to "Open With" (In the Right-Click Context Menu on Windows XP) and have my application be able to handle the file given. I have no idea on where to start or where to look so I thought I'd ask here. Thanks.

Comment: question is how to know that your application run by main application exe or with open with dialog to your application file extension

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at this Windows KB article:

"How To Associate a File Extension with Your Application (Win32)"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185453

It looks like it gives example code for how to do this in VBScript (?), but it looks like it goes through the Registry paths you need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I believe this is defined in the registry. E.g. MSAccess is defined as:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.Application.11\shell\Edit]
@="&Edit"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.Application.11\shell\Edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Programmer\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\MSACCESS.EXE\" /NOSTARTUP \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.Application.11\shell\Edit\ddeexec]
@="[SetForeground][ShellOpenDatabase \"%1\"]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.Application.11\shell\Edit\ddeexec\Application]
@="Msaccess"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.Application.11\shell\Edit\ddeexec\IfExec]
@="[SHELLNOOP]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.Application.11\shell\Edit\ddeexec\Topic]
@="ShellSystem"
```

A GUI also exists in Folder settings -> File types.

Br. Morten

Comment: the question is how to handle the file after is open by my application

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the run dialog box, and enter: `regedit` (Registry Editor)

Go to: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` and create a subkey named: "Open With YourApp", create another subkey under the newly created one named "command". On its Default value, enter the path to your exe, then add "%1" at the end for the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

In program.cs, add the indicated lines below:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var mainForm = new MainForm();

        // Add these lines:
        // ----------------------------------------------
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Count() >= 2)
            mainForm.LoadFile(args[1]);
        // ----------------------------------------------

        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

Where `LoadFile(string filePath)` is your method that handles the file that is passed in from outside.